# LLVM passes int array by copy rather than reference?

Tags: c++

Using LLVM 4.2 (through Xcode 4.6.3) to compile a project for school.  According to the professor, G++ will pass int arrays by reference (so you can modify the array in a separate function and the original array will be changed), but in LLVM it seems like it passes by copy (so the original array isn't modified).  Is this true about LLVM or is this a project-specific issue?

Comment: In C++, arrays decay to pointers to their first element in many contexts, including when used by themselves as an expression.  That means there's no way to pass an array by value (barring embedding it in a structure or a similar hack).  Can you show some example about what you're talking about?

Comment: Well, I recompiled the original source code I was given to show you what happens and it worked this time...  Don't know why it didn't work the first time before I changed it, but oh well.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably post some simple code that displays the issue, along with the behavior you expect and what you observe. Just by your description I would guess that g++ is likely to have similarly unexpected behavior and it probably has nothing to do with whether arrays are passed by value or by reference.

Comment: Are you talking about Clang or the LLVM framework? What sort of array? What sort of code? There's a ton of context missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array will always be passed by pointer. If the original array is not modified, there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in your code, really.

Keep in mind that the professor is talking about `int[N]`, not `std::array<int, N>`